# How to generate random number that start with the same value in MATLAB and C#

Tags: c#, matlab, .net-core, matlab-compiler

I am writing the same program in C# and MATLAB. The only issue I am facing is the different values generated in MATLAB and C#, although I am providing the same seed value.

In other words, the random numbers generated by both compilers are not matching.

For example:

**C#:**

```
Random rand = new Random(10);
double val = rand.Next(1, 100);
```

it starting random number is: 95

**MATLAB:**

```
rng(10);
r2 = randi([1 100],1,1)
```

While it starting random number is: 77

Can anyone help me?

How to let both compilers begin with the same random number?

Comment: There are tons of algorithms for producing the same pseudo-random numbers. You'll have to implement the same algorithm in Matlab and C#.

Comment: Can you refer a link

Comment: From [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) it seems that matlab normally uses a *Mersenne Twister*

Comment: But this also implies that it can use any of various algorithms. But without the sources you will have to rely on trial&error anyway..

Comment: It did not work. You are right, we are not aware  of their  internal algorithms for random number generation.

Comment: @jehan sadly there are too many implementations of the same algorithm, so finding two implementations that generate exactly the same numbers is difficult.

Comment: Yes, @xanatos! I think that for time being, I should generate a large number of the random numbers in C#, store it in a file, then import it to MATLAB, and each time use new number using index +++ . hahha. I think it will be a bad answer, but a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write your function of generating a random object and initialize it with the same parameters.

Comment: For example? I tried but unable,  can you explain more if you really know the answer?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: First way:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html
Also, you can generate c++ code for run it from c#.

Second way is realize simple pseudo-random algorithm on MATLAB and C#.
Third way is study the algorithm of pseudo-random numbers in MATLAB and to port it to C#.

I would choose the second option if the quality of the pseudo random is not critical.

Comment: Alternatively, you can pre-generate a set of random values and select them sequentially.

Comment: Yes, the same I was thinking (see comments above with the question). I will pre-generate random values, and will use them in both programs.